# Django test database not being used with custom test runner

Tags: python, django, postgresql, unit-testing

I am using Django 1.9 and have written a custom test runner.  I cannot figure out why my production database is being used instead of my test_ database.  I've read quite a lot of the Django docs to no avail.  The name of my production database is zippymeals, so my test database should be test_zippymeals.  But my tests seems to be running against the zippymeals database, not test_zippymeals.  Here is the code for my custom test runner:

```
class TestRunner(DiscoverRunner):

def __init__(self, pattern=None, top_level=None, verbosity=1, interactive=True, failfast=False, **kwargs):
    super(TestRunner, self).__init__(pattern, top_level, verbosity, interactive, failfast, **kwargs)

def setup_databases(self, **kwargs):
    bash_cmd = "createdb -T zippymeals_template test_zippymeals"
    process = subprocess.Popen(bash_cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.communicate()[0]

def teardown_databases(self, old_config, **kwargs):
    bash_cmd = "dropdb test_zippymeals"
    process = subprocess.Popen(bash_cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.communicate()[0]
```

and I set the following in my settings.py file:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'tests.test_runner.TestRunner'
```

I'm using PostgreSQL, so my custom test runner uses the zippymeals_template database (which is an empty structure of my database) to create an empty test_zippymeals database.  The test_zippymeals database gets created fine, it's just not being used when I run my tests.  Also, I've tried doing the following with no luck:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'zippymeals',
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'test_zippymeals'
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to inherit from DiscoverRunner and ensure that the test_ database is being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call super class method for `setup_databases` which is the method responsible for setting the proper alias for the test database. E.g.

```
def setup_databases(self, **kwargs):
    db = super(TestRunner, self).setup_database(**kwargs)
    .... # your code goes here
    return db
```

Here is a more generic version of setup_database method for running tests on postgres databases:

```
class CustomTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):

    def setup_databases(self, **kwargs):
        # your code goes here
        bash_cmd = "createdb -T zippymeals_template test_zippymeals"
        process = subprocess.Popen(bash_cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        process.communicate()[0]

        # force Django to connect to the correct db for tests
        connection = db.connections['default']
        db_conf = connection.settings_dict
        db_conf['NAME'] = db_conf['TEST']['NAME']
        connection.connect()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and the help, although I don't understand how this fixes the problem.  I don't want to use the default test database creation.  If I call super.setup_databases(), then Django tries to create the test database for me, which is exactly what I don't want to happen.  I want to create the database myself (no migrations).  Right now if I do what you suggest, the test runner fails with a table not found error message, as it should.  So I guess what I'm really asking, is how to get subclass of DiscoverRunner to correctly alias (?) or make the tests point to test_zippymeals?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a sample implementation of a CustomTestRunner which does not rely on Django's super.setup_database.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I'll take a look at it in depth and see if I can get it to work.